# How should I install Linux on Windows Vista PC?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, windows-vista

I am doing .net programming in addition to c and c++ development and want more flexibility on my home machine.  I want to be able to have both Linux (probably Ubuntu) and Windows Vista on my home computer.  Is there a way I can install both and on boot be prompted for which one to start?  Is there a way to set Windows to default?

I have seen this before in CS labs in undergrad.

Also, I assume there would be no problem if I were to use Windows 32-bit along with Ubuntu 64-bit.  Any advise?

Comment: Have you tried using a Virtual Machine? This is essentially an operating system running within an operating system, you can work on both at the same time. However, if you run into a RAM problem, either [use an external USB](http://lifehacker.com/5573801/turn-a-usb-flash-drive-into-extra-virtual-ram) or you can use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) to make a USB installer. (Do an advanced restart in BIOS mode and install it on an empty hard disk partition). There are tutorials for this online

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The latest versions of Ubuntu include an installer called [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/), which installs Ubuntu as a windows application (ie: it can be uninstalled from Add/Remove programs) and sets up the dual boot for you! It's great for those who want to give Linux a try without a system overhaul!

Comment: Is there something like this for other distros, like OpenSUSE and Fedora?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure. Wubi is the only one I've heard of, but I think it's a great concept and would love to see it in more distros!

Comment: hmmm... thought this may not be worth the effort (IMHO virtualization was always the best option), but after looking at it for a bit I really like the idea. Kudos for a great suggestion.

Comment: there is one for debian which you can get from here.
http://goodbye-microsoft.com/

However if you are trying out linux for the first time Ubuntu is probably the path of least resistance.

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it - and it's a hell of a lot faster than Virtual Box or VMWare - at least in my experience.

Comment: There is also [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) which allows you to boot to a USB, and install Linux on an empty hard drive partition. It supports a LOT of distros, including but definitely not limited to Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, Kali,

Answer (score 8):

You can dual boot, but I would recommend using a Virtual Machine for what you want to do.

Look at [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) and [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/virtualpc/default.mspx).

For more information on Virtual PC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Virtual_PC

For more information on VMWare: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation

You should note that dual booting Windows and Linux can be a little risky and is a bit permanent. Running in a Virtual Machine means that you can run the Linux install in a window and not worry about it affecting your development machine at all. The software will not know the difference, so your testing is not affected.

Consider that the Virtual Machine is like a sandbox, where you can try new and different things out, without fear of consequences.

Virtual machines do run with a bit of overhead, and therefore you should not expect to be playing games or anything through them. I would say it is very much like logging into a machine through Remote Desktop (good LAN connection) as far as performance goes.

EDIT: There is also [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) that you could check out. Thanks for the helpers in my comments for that one.

Answer (score 3):

I, too, recommend using a virtual machine for this purpose.

I've had problems with Virtual PC on some Linux distros (Fedora Core comes to mind), but no problems with [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) or [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Think very hard before installing another operating system even as dual boot. It is rarely simple, even with installers like Ubuntu's that don't require you to mess around on a command line. There is a good risk you'll spend days trying to get your usual OS back to normal especially if you're using Vista.

VMWare and Virtual PC are both good options. Do a test install on one of these and use the OS for a while before making the decision to install.

One other great thing about using a virtual machine is that you only have to worry about getting your network settings sorted on your main OS, because VMWare (etc) will borrow those.

Also, try using the operating system on Live CD or DVD to start with if at all possible. You may also find that you can run an OS from a USB stick. This is obviously good for portability - but note that you can also carry your virtual machines on a removable USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is go to http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download and follow the directions.  I downloaded Ubuntu, burned it to CD, and rebooted with the CD in the drive.  I did not have to get a second hard drive or worry about it messing with my Vista Home Premium installation.

With Ubuntu (as with most distros with a Live CD install) all you need to do is pop in a disc, boot, and click through the menus.  The dual boot is set up perfectly by default, you don't even have to think about it.  I've done this with Ubuntu, Debian, PC Linux OS, Freespire, and Xandros on my Vista Home Premium machine and they all worked that way.

If you are paranoid, then you should back up your PC.  As cheap as hard drives (USB or internal) are these days, there really is no excuse to not have a full back up of your system.  It's too easy.  I use Acronis True Image, but I've heard good things about Norton Ghost as well.

Regadless, you don't need Wubi or VMWare, or any virtual anything, a straight install with a dual boot set up is the default on a typical Live CD Linux install and it works even with Vista.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it different ways over the years, and I'd say using a virtual machine is the one that I like best.  I've tried both VMWare and VirtualBox, both free, and I like VirtualBox a little better because you can use it with the .iso straight.   You don't need somebody to have created a virtual machine image for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to actually run Linux as an application on Windows so you get Linux running at almost full speed but also the ability to run Windows applications along side it. Check it out at http://www.colinux.org/.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to play with it yet, but an option that looks promising for me is a tool in Ubuntu to create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu on it. It has the benefit of a live cd (no effect on your system), better performance than a live CD and the ability to persist your data from session to session. I've used Wubi before, but I can't remember why I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "cygwin".

This istalls a "linux like" windowing application within your windows 
environment. It has good support for gcc and most of the standard
gnu/linux development tools.

You dont have to mess with dual boot. Its especially good for testing
windows to/from unix communictions as you can get everything up and
running in one box.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called 'Dual booting'. it allows one to choose which operating system to boot at the start. It's well supported in Linux, especially Ubuntu. Just install Ubuntu and it will set up dual booting by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could go either way, a dual-boot or use a VM. I think it depends on whether you'll want to use any Windows apps while developing in the Linux environment. If so, I'd go with a VM, otherwise, [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/dual_boot_windows_xp_vista_ubuntu_feisty)'s a tutorial for setting up a dual-boot computer. It has a part on installing both OSes, and a part on if you already have Windows installed.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is a great (Ubuntu specific) solution.. The only problem I've found was installing Wubi on a FAT formatted Windows partition - I had serious problems then. Also, it might run slightly slower, as there is another layer when doing disk acccess, but I can't say I've noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I dual boot Vista Ultimate 32-bit and Ubuntu 8.10 beta 64-bit with no problems.  The key thing, in my opinion, is to have a completely separate hard drive to install Ubuntu on.  That removes a lot of the risk since you don't have to fuss around partitioning your primary HDD and makes removing Ubuntu very straightforward as well if you decide you don't want it.

Just be careful and pay attention on which drive you select when you do the install.  It's easy for me to tell them apart since my Linux drive is a different size than my main Vista and data storage drives.

If you'd rather go the VM route, VMware Player works well, and I've heard good things about VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

try a live cd install of ubuntu :D

creating a  bootable flash disk is easy - unetbootin from sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

I have dual booted Ubuntu and Xp many times with absolutely no problems. I doubt you could do the virtual thing with one OS 32 bit and the other 64. This would not be a problem with a dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems using wubi and my boot into windows7 is now unstable at best, so given the choice would favour a VM solution in hindsight. However on other machines I have run Ubuntu Live on USB (installed using pendrivelinux.com) by picking the try ubuntu option at boot and that has worked well and was quite quick to get going.